# Какая связь должна быть между Cart, Order и Product?

Tags: sql, orm, activerecord, uml

Не могу понять как нужно организовывать таблицы\модели и связи между ними. Какие связи должны быть между сущностями Корзины, Заказа и Товара в настоящем интернет-магазине? Пользователей можно опустить, с ними, вроде, все понятно: У Пользователя есть одна Корзина.

Comment: Корзина-Товар - 1:N. Заказ-Товар - 1:N. Корзина и Заказ - по сути одна и та же сущность. Корзина - это до оформления, заказ - после оформления. И даже то, что у юзера строго одна корзина (заказов, понятно, много) - неочевидно...

Answer (score 0):

Вам понадобится еще одна таблица CartProduct с ключем на Cart.(многие к одному)
Таким образом связываем Products с CartProduct(один к многим),Order(id_cart) с Cart(id_cart)(один к многим)
Пишите если что - подумаем еще)